# Lookup entries that depend on ManyToMany Field w/ > 10 entries

Tags: python, django

I want to query all events that have more than 10 attendee entries. Do you have advice how to achieve that?

`events = Event.objects.filter(attendees__count > 10)`

```
class Attendance(HashidModel, TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attendances"
    )
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attendances"
    )
    [...]

class Event(HashidModel, TimeStampedModel):
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="events_attending",
        through="Attendance",
    )
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from django.db.models import Count

events = Event.objects.annotate(Count('attendees')).filter(attendees__count__gt=10)
```

This annotates each Entry object in the queryset with the number of its attendees (this becomes `attendees__count` by default) and then filters those Events by those that have `attendees__count` greater than 10.

If you wanted the reverse (less than or equal to) it would be `attendees__count__lte`.

Comment: Glad I could help